# freemarker error loading template

Tags: java, freemarker

Getting the below exception, does anyone have solution for this 
also as shown in mongodb tutorial , its actually .ftl , here i have given html file 
And im unable to create .ftl file

```
package com.mongodb;

    import freemarker.template.Configuration;
    import freemarker.template.Template;

    import java.io.StringWriter;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    /**
     * Created by tadoori on 10/20/2016.
     */
    public class HelloworldFreemarkerStyle {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(HelloworldFreemarkerStyle.class, "/");

            try {

                Template helloTemplate = configuration.getTemplate("hello.html");
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                Map<String, Object> helloMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                helloMap.put("name", "Freemark");

                helloTemplate.process(helloMap, writer);

                System.out.println(writer);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is below on running the java file

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources does not exist.
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:125)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:122)
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:108)
    at com.mongodb.HelloworldFreemarkerStyle.main(HelloworldFreemarkerStyle.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: try passing absolute path for template or debug and inspect what path is called

Comment: Now after passing absolute path "C:\Users\tadoori\M101J\src\resources\hello.html "          now its says java.io.FilenotFoudException: resource does not exist

Comment: configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(HelloworldFreemarkerStyle.class, "C:\\Users\\tadoori\\M101J\\src\\resources\\hello.html");

Comment: comment thas row and try with first attempt

Comment: ok I commented and ran it ....it gives below output   java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources does not exist.

Comment: try use cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/where/you/store/templates")) instead of setClassForTemplateLoading, and only file name in getTemplate()

Comment: I did as you said still the same error ...is there some settings to be done in Intellij idea 2016?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code in my test project created whith Idea2016 (freemarker v.2.3.23) and work perfecty.

```
import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        try {

            Template helloTemplate = configuration.getTemplate("hello.html");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            Map<String, Object> helloMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            helloMap.put("name", "Freemark");

            helloTemplate.process(helloMap, writer);

            System.out.println(writer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

File hello.html is in project directory root.

Comment: Hi thanks, for the response aactually its the issue with windows 7 I guess , because i tried in windows 10 and it worked